# How to avoid "Method could be a function" warning within attrs custom validation function

Tags: python, pylint, python-attrs

Given the following code:

```py
# check.py
import attr
from attr._make import Attribute


@attr.frozen
class Example:
    x: int = attr.ib()

    @x.validator
    def _validate_x(self, _: Attribute, value: int) -> None:
        assert value > 0
```

Running `pylint check.py` will return:

```
************* Module check
check.py:12:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
```

Granted this code is a pretty contrived example, but I'm not sure how I should alter the code to please this message?

## edit

The following works to ignore:

```py
@attr.frozen
class Example:
    # pylint: disable=no-self-use
    x: int = attr.ib()

    @x.validator
    def _validate_x(self, _: Attribute, value: int) -> None:
        assert value > 0
```

Comment: Have you considered *ignoring it?*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
# pylint: disable=R0201
```

Comment: note : `I0023: 'R0201' is cryptic: use '# pylint: disable=no-self-use' instead (use-symbolic-message-instead)`